# Archimedean spiral: arc length of coil

Tags: calculus

Are the arc lengths of the coils - i.e. the parts $0-2\pi$, $2\pi-4\pi$, etc. - in arithmetic progression?

Comment: It would be nice if you could supply a formula for an Archimedean spiral. You might like to change the question tag: arc-length is very much differential geometry, it requires integrating certain derivatives. 

$$L = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\dot{x}+\dot{y}} \, \operatorname{d}\!t$$

Comment: The tag is wrong.

Comment: @FlybyNight maybe squares forgotten

Comment: @Paul Stephenson For one rotation radius increases proportionally with  $  \theta $ ...so naturally perimeter length also increases similarly.

Answer (score 1):

Given the formula for an Archimedean spiral $r=a+b\theta$, the arc length of turn $n$ is $$\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi} \sqrt {\left(\frac {dr}{d\theta}\right)^2+ r^2 }d\theta
\\=\int_{(n-1)\pi}^{n\pi}\sqrt {b^2+(a+b \theta)^2}d\theta
\\=\int_{(n-1)\pi-\frac ab}^{n\pi-\frac ab}\sqrt{b^2+b^2\phi^2} d\phi
\\=b\int_{(n-1)\pi-\frac ab}^{n\pi-\frac ab}\sqrt{1+\phi^2} d\phi
\\=\left.\frac b2\left(\phi\sqrt{1+\phi^2}+\sinh^{-1}\phi\right)\right |_{(n-1)\pi-\frac ab}^{n\pi-\frac ab}$$ which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sqrt%281%2bx%5E2%29) shows is not linear.